# state_machine for both if & else

Tags: ruby, state-machine

I have the following states `:A`, `:B`, `:C`.

```
require 'state_machine'

class Example
  property :value, String
  def test_condition
    value == "hmm"
  end
  state_machine :state, :initial => :A do
    event :my_event do
      transition [:A, :B] => :C, :if => :test_condition
      transition :A => :B, :unless => :test_condition
    end
  end
  def my_event
    #Some Logic
  end
end
```

When `:test_condition` is true, the state goes from `:A` to `:C` but when it is false, both states go from `:A` to `:B`, the problem being when my state is `:B` and `:my_event` is triggered, in which case the state doesn't go to `:C` and stays at `:B`. Am I missing something?

I debugged my code using rubymine, and found that, when the state is at `:B` and event is triggered, the breakpoint doesn't stop at `:test_condition` method; it doesn't get called at all.

The docs only discuss `if` or `else` once at a time, and nothing is mentioned related to `if State_1 else State_2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you def my_event? I think you should use :do for this, I also replaced datamapper property to the plain attr_accessor.

Here is the code that working:

```
require 'state_machine'

class Example
  attr_accessor :value

  def test_condition
    value == "hmm"
  end
  state_machine :state, :initial => :A do
    event :my_event do
      transition [:A, :B] => :C, :if => :test_condition
      transition :A => :B, :unless => :test_condition
    end
  end
end


ex = Example.new()
puts ex.state

ex.my_event
puts ex.state

ex.value ='hmm'

ex.my_event
puts ex.state
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: Whenever the my_event method is called, it should alter the state based on the test_condition return value...

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help, the issue was I did not include the super keyword in my method

Comment: yes, use super to call inner method, also if you use initialize in the class, call `super()` in the end.